# .NET ORM help needed

Tags: .net, orm

I have SQL server db ready with simple (not many constraints) tables. Now i need to generate DAL and object classes for tables.

How much can .NET ORM (like NHibernate or any other free FW you suggest) help in this ? Basically helping out with laborious tasks of writing class and db access functions. I will better spend time in writing business logic for those object classes.

Will it be easy to add/alter tables later ? I have conceptual idea about ORMs but no practical experience in using any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [Linq to Sql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx#linqtosql_topic1) or [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to autogenerate your classes as well as Data Access functionality.

You can drag and drop your database tables into the DBML (L2S) or EDMX (EF) from within Visual Studio and it will build your classes with members mapped one-to-one to columns, as well as any relationships you have defined.

To create `Linq to Sql Classes` or `ADO.NET Entity Data Model` follow these steps:

- right-click in Visual Studio on one of your Projects
- Add = > New Item
- Select `Linq to Sql Classes` or `ADO.NET Entity Data Model`
- This will create a blank design view for creating and customizing your classes.
- User `Server Explorer` to open a connection to your database
- Drag and Drop tables onto the DBML or EDMX canvas and Save when finished.

For instance:

- table `User` becomes class `User`
- If table `User` has column `FirstName` it becomes property `FirstName`
- If table `User` has a relationship with table `Contact` it will generate `IList<Contact> Contacts` on your `User` class. This will let you write code like `user.Contacts.Where(c => c.ContactId == 7000)` from within the generated `DataContext`

If you need a more customized way to map your tables you can use [SQLMetal](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2007/11/25/sqlmetal-and-linq.aspx) which will also generate your classes but allow you to make changes. For instance, converting `int` properties to `enums`.

---

[NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/Default.aspx) is also a good option and has come a long way.

Comment: drag and drop into DBML ? where is option of DBML in VS.few direct steps to follow would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

There are many tools that will generate DALs for you.

[SubSonic](http://subsonicproject.com/) is not an ORM, but a code generation tool that will generate a DAL for you.

There is [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399572.aspx) and [Linq to SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx) (from Microsoft) that will also generate a DAL for you, with a design surface in visual studio.

With all of these adding and altering tables required regenerating the DAL, so changes and customizations to these files can get lost.

Comment: SubSonic is an ORM.  It's possible to change the database without losing changes on the code side if you are using things like partial classes correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Both [Linq2Sql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx) and [Entity framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) can help you with this to a great extent. With regards to your question about updating tables: Yes, it is quite easy to update tables later. At least a lot easier than if you had written everything by hand (where you would have to do modifications by hand too).

Comment: Is there much learning curve or i can simply start using ?  How do i generate classes and DAL with linq2sql (it looks simpler than EF) , does it give any tool ?

Comment: @Munish Goyal: I don't think that the learning curve is very steep. Yes, there is a tool. You just drag and drop your tables in visual studio. All you have to do is add a "Linq2Sql data classes" file to your project and get started dragging tables from "server explorer". easy as that.

Comment: "Linq2Sql data classes" file ? .cs file or a template ? pl elaborate. wud be helpful

Comment: Great. thanks. Do i need to try NHibernate for any related feature or this linq2sql will suffice ?  Further, i want to accept both answers, yours and below one @Hunter@ How to do that ?

Comment: @Munish Goyal: NHibernate is in no way related to Linq2Sql and you can use Linq2Sql by itself just fine. You can only accept one as the answers, so just pick one.

Comment: What are these OnChanging etc. There is one constructor given and inside it is OnCreated(). Where are the private vars initialized ? What are side effects of setting a property. does it immediately commit to DB ?

Comment: @Munish Goyal: The changes are saved when you call `SubmitChanges` on your datacontext. If you have more detailed questions try asking them in a new question. These comments are not suited for that :-)

Comment: 1 more thing. is the class object tightly tied with table record. What if table record gets modified via backdoor ? does this linq2sql class handle all such scenarios ? sry ..asking all details, but i need to decide this quickly.

Comment: @Munish Goyal: No, linq2sql does not constantly poll data to see if a row has changed via some other manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

Nhibernate will handle all of your data access logic.
I recommend that you define every foreign key and primary key that you can.
It is also simpler to have an explicit primary key instead of a composite primary key.

To generate the object classes, I recommend using T4 templates.   There are various sample templates available online and it is relatively straight forward to write your own to do exactly what you want.

It is also a good idea to let these object classes serve as data containers and implement your business logic in separate classes that use these DAL classes.   This will simplify being able to regenerate them should the underlying tables change.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late the party, but Cocoon ORM on Nuget and Github is good.  It writes the data access code dynamically. http://guidelinetech.github.io/cocoon-orm/

Feature list below from the website:

- Automapping of database fields to domain object properties
- AutoCrud with auto Join creation on get (select)
- Automapping domain object properties to stored procedure parameters
- Dynamically creates easy to inspect parametrized SQL that is execution plan and cache friendly
- Uses simple data annotations similar to that of the Entity Framework
- Regression and benchmarking tools for the truly paranoid (like us)
- Table generation tools for use in a code first environment
- Class generation tools for use in code second environment
- Easily create non-integer sequential unique IDs using the included Comb GUID or Sequential UID generator.
- Compatible with SQL Server 2008/2012/20014/+ and Azure SQL (workable with other TSQL databases)
- Use the Cocoon ORM libraries in your own proprietary code under the weak copyleft LGPL license (changes to Cocoon ORM itself must be
  shared. Please let us know so we can brain things together!)

Answer (score 0):

Try Vega https://github.com/aadreja/vega. One of the best & fastest .net ORM with enterprise features.